# Domino Server 9.0.1 DAS option is not available in Additional Server mode

Tags: lotus-domino

I installed Domino Server 9.0.1 and lotus Notes. The Enable DAS option is not available at all in the web Engine tab at all.

How can II enable it as 9.0.1 must support it by default!  I am using the Enterprise version. Do I need to install some plugin?

**UPDATE**

I tried to uninstall it and install it again ,this time selecting `standalone mode` and the option is available if "Load Internet configurations from Server\Internet Sites documents" to disabled  as @Knut Herrmann mentioned.

The issue is that I have to use this domino server as additional server and in that mode I am not getting this option

**UPDATE 2**

I am using Domino server 9.0.1 in additional server mode, that connects to a main server for syncing the data which has a Domino server 8.5.3 . I am not able to get the option under Web Engine tab to enable DAS.

Comment: Could you please point me to the documentation on how to enable DAS for Domino Server 9.0.1? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set field "Load Internet configurations from Server\Internet Sites documents" to `disabled` on server document's basic tab:

[image]

Only if this option is disabled the section "Domino Access Services" on tab "Internet Protocols / Domino Web Engine" is visible.

Comment: Your original question was kind of development related because Designer helped to find out why "Domino Access Services" part was hidden. With your updates, it's really an admin question now and you'll find the experts on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/ for this.

Comment: can you migrate this question to serverfault??

Comment: Just copy & paste :)